# Can a user manipulate cookies?

Tags: php, cookies

I have a question regarding usage of cookies for standard login purposes. Say my php script saves a cookie into a users computer each time he logs in. The cookie value is say "Mike" after his username at the website. Can that user somehow manipulate that cookie in his browser to change the value to say "Admin" so suddenly he has access to administration of the website?

If this could happen how to solve such security risk?

--

Additionally... What if someone was to copy cookies from my browser, either he would stare at my computer screen and copy cookies and values into his computer or such intruder could steal cookies from my browser via JavaScript.

How is that taken care of?

Comment: Yes. *Do not store information that you don't want tampered with in cookies.* You can use sessions instead.

Comment: As Waleed said, yes it can be done.  It's [trivially easy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/edit-cookies/).  You could look into using sessions for storing info.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, that is a security problem, which extends to any information provided by the client.

Cookies are stored on the user's machine.  They can be modified in any way.  In fact, the cookies can just be created on the fly and sent via several utilities for making HTTP requests.  It isn't even a browser problem.

Never trust any data that comes from the client.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a user can manipulate cookies if they're stored on their computer. 
Use a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Answer (score 3):

A 'session' is the server-side storage of connection-relative information that is linked to the user through a variable which is passed back and forth, most often a cookie, however logically, anywhere will do if both your client and server can handle it.

This 'session' is often represented by an integer which the client and server both know.

The problem is, if another client has a session open on the server, we (as a client) could 'hi-jack' this session by replacing our given id with a random id until one is found. The server would now believe we are in fact the other use and could give us access to their private informatin.

For this reason, we have 'keys'. A key is a unique, often alphanumeric, code which is changed on each request-response pair with the server, ensuring that only those who have the latest key are able to gain access.

Comment: but sessions have an overhead on the server resources

Answer (score 2):

**YES**

They can manipulate, edit, modify, create and delete cookies.

You should only store a hash key that you use on the server to look up in a database anything that should be secure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, users can manipulate cookies.  The best way to handle it is to not store user credentials in such a manner that they can gain admin access by changing their user name.

The specifics on how to do this are pretty deep, but a good start would be to just store the users's session identifier instead.  That has its own issues, but won't let people break things quite so easily.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are clientside which means that they can be read, write and delete by the client. A  cookie manager plugin makes it easier to change the cookie value.

> http://www.ehow.com/how_7149468_edit-cookies-computer.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes a user can easily manipulate the cookies by just going to cooking option which all popular browser provide